# Post method for HTTP redirect not working in nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, express, redirect, http-redirect

[image: Post with follow redirect enabled]

[image: Post with simple http request]

Hi I have a simple expressjs based server which is acting as a proxy.
 It performs a new http request as per the incoming request and  after getting the response it sends it back to original request. The below code works fine but it fails when the response contains **statusCode 301 , statusMessage Moved Permanently** .
I tried to make  use of [follow-redirects](https://www.npmjs.com/package/follow-redirects) but this seems to  subsequently convert my post request to that of a get request.
The below is my code

```
    "use strict";
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
const http = require("http");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var followRedirects = require('follow-redirects');
app.use(bodyParser.json());


  function pipeResponse (source, sink) {

    console.log("***********Response ***************");

    console.log("->>statusCode "+source.statusCode);
    console.log("->>statusMessage "+source.statusMessage);

    sink.statusCode = source.statusCode;
    sink.statusMessage = source.statusMessage;

    console.log("----------Response Headers ---------");

    Object.keys(source.headers).
        forEach((name) => {

            console.log(name+" : "+source.headers[name]);
            sink.setHeader(name, source.headers[name]);
        });
    console.log("-------------------------------------");   

    source.on("data", (ce) => {
        sink.write(ce);
        console.log("data  present" );
    });
    source.on("end", () => sink.end());

    console.log("**************************************");

}

// used to handle both query/read and modify operations on entityset people
app.all("/api/people", (req, res) => {

    // sample service 
    var options = {"headers": {}};
    options.host = "services.odata.org";
    options.path = "/TripPinRESTierService/(S(3mslpb2bc0k5ufk24olpghzx))/People";
    options.method = req.method;
    console.log("request method type " + req.method);

    if(req.headers["content-type"]){     
        options.headers["content-type"] = req.headers["content-type"];
    }

    var payLoad ;
    payLoad = req.body;
    //var proxyRequest = followRedirects.http.request(options, (backendres) => pipeResponse(backendres, res));
    var proxyRequest = http.request(options, (backendres) => pipeResponse(backendres, res));
    proxyRequest.on("error", (err) => {

        console.error("request failed",err);

    });
    if (payLoad) {
        console.log("payload data " + JSON.stringify(payLoad));
        proxyRequest.write(JSON.stringify(payLoad));
    }

    proxyRequest.end();


});

app.listen(8080, () => {
});
```

Can some body please help me to solve this .

The post body is as follow

```
{
    "UserName":"lewisblack",
    "FirstName":"Lewis",
    "LastName":"Black",
    "Emails":[
        "lewisblack@example.com"
    ],
    "AddressInfo": [
    {
      "Address": "187 Suffolk Ln.",
      "City": {
        "Name": "Boise",
        "CountryRegion": "United States",
        "Region": "ID"
      }
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use an existing proxy implementation such as [`http-proxy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy)?

Comment: I have stripped down most of my original code. What I understand is that http-proxy is used for proxying to servers that are already defined in the hard coded targets. In my original scenarios the resolved target servers are dynamic in nature. So, I had to implement my own proxy server.

Comment: That's also possible with http-proxy. You can define an individual target for every single request you proxy. Check out the [second use case](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy#setup-a-stand-alone-proxy-server-with-custom-server-logic) on the modules docs.

Comment: Hi Lucas, I will surely try this out. In any case do you have any samples which I can refer to..

Comment: Create your proxy server once with `const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});` then call `proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://127.0.0.1:5060' });` in any request you want to proxy.